# Getting new Migrations generated after 3.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have upgraded my app to rails 3.1 following Ryan Bates' instructions in [Railscast Episode 282](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1).  Everything is working wonderfully except that new migrations generated are still following the old style of

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

How do I upgrade things so new migrations are generated in the new style of:

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Comment: what does `rails -v` say? My guess is that you updated the Gemfile but not the gem that's installed on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [3.1.0 generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/migration.rb) only uses `change` if it detects a migration that adds something. Maybe you didn't call `rails g migration AddSomething`?